# Parameters in Url Without any sign like?

Tags: javascript, html

show URL some URL that is not exists!

need to show URL like this:
`test.com/compare/id-1/id-2/dkp-3/dkp-4/`

but act like this:
`test.com/compare/?id-1&id-2&dkp-3&dkp-4`

Its an HTML Page and load data with JS.

Comment: Are you want to convert / instead of & ?

Comment: Whatever coming after `?` is a query string.

Comment: What you are asking for requires you to write some server-side code. It would help us find the right answer for you if we knew what server software you are using and if you can explain why using the ```?param1=A&param2=B...``` format is not useful, as this is the standard way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

> **Web forms**
>
> One of the original uses was to contain the content of an HTML form,
>   also known as web form. In particular, when a form containing the
>   fields `field1`, `field2`, `field3` is submitted, the content of the
>   fields is encoded as a query string as follows:
>
> ```
> field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...
> ```
>
> - The query string is composed of a series of field-value pairs.
> - Within each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals    sign, "=".
> - The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, "&" (or semicolon,    ";" for URLs embedded in HTML and not generated by a
>     .... See below).
>
> While there is no definitive standard, most web frameworks allow
>   multiple values to be associated with a single field (e.g.
>   field1=value1&field1=value2&field2=value3).[5][6]
>
> For each field of the form, the query string contains a pair
>   field=value. Web forms may include fields that are not visible to the
>   user; these fields are included in the query string when the form is
>   submitted
>
> This convention is a W3C recommendation.[4] W3C recommends that all
>   web servers support semicolon separators in addition to ampersand
>   separators[7] to allow application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings
>   in URLs within HTML documents without having to entity escape
>   ampersands.
>
> The form content is only encoded in the URL's query string when the
>   form submission method is GET. The same encoding is used by default
>   when the submission method is POST, but the result is submitted as the
>   HTTP request body rather than being included in a modified URL.[1]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Isnt there a really better way to pass parameters to a page?
The page is html form and use a rest api to send and recive data to forms.

Comment: I have a compare html form and need to pass products ids to compare. But dont want to use query string.